# Filling PDF form with python pdfrw causes local diacritic signs (polish) to change font

Tags: python, fonts, pdfrw

have anyone encountered a problem that filling a PDF form with python (fx. pdfrw) causes the font for that specific letter to change. How can I solve that?

Comment: Could you provide any code please ?, it's going to be easier to help you

Comment: hey, I solved that I think, the problem was with the template pdf not the code itself